# How to modify iOS WkWebKit Settings

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, settings

I would like to set some parameters on a web view like I do under Android but other than enabling JavaScript I haven't been able to find the place to do so.  Can I make these settings under Swift / iOS?

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(false);
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(false);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);

webView.clearHistory();
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearFormData();
```